# Azure IOT Module - Unable to subscribe to message

Tags: python-3.x, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I'm trying to get more comfortable working with Azure IOT and decided that I wanted to start sending my own telemetry data instead of the "tempSensor" demo that they have provided.

I created this "basic_device" module.

```
import time
import json
import iothub_client
# pylint: disable=E0611
from iothub_client import IoTHubClient, IoTHubTransportProvider, IoTHubMessage, IoTHubError

# Connection string and protocol set
CONNECTION_STRING = "REMOVED-FOR-POST"
PROTOCOL = IoTHubTransportProvider.MQTT

def set_sample_rate(sample_rate=0.1):
    """Creates a decorator that has the given sample_rate."""
    def decorate_sample_rate(func):
        """The actual decorator."""
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            """Wrapper method."""
            fname = func.__name__
            # If first time, use the last time
            if fname not in args[0]._time:
                args[0]._time[fname] = args[0]._time_last

            # Check if it's time to add this message
            if args[0]._time_last - args[0]._time[fname] >= sample_rate:
                component_msg = func(*args, **kwargs)
                for comp in component_msg:
                    args[1][comp] = component_msg[comp]
                args[0]._time[fname] = args[0]._time_last

            return args[1]

        return wrapper
    return decorate_sample_rate

def send_confirmation_callback(message, result, user_context):
    """Send confirmation upon sucessful message."""
    print ( "IoT Hub responded to message with status: %s" % (result) )


class SimulateDevice():
    def __init__(self, msg_max=100):
        self._client = IoTHubClient(CONNECTION_STRING, PROTOCOL)
        self._time_start = time.time()
        self._time_last = time.time()
        self._time = {}
        self._msg_count = 0
        self._msg_max = msg_max

    @set_sample_rate(2)
    def _noisy_wave_message(self, msg):
        """Create a message that is noisy."""
        dt = time.time() - self._time_start
        component_msg = {
            'noisy_sinus': np.sin(dt / 100.0) +  np.random.normal(0, 0.25, 1)[0],
            'noisy_cosine': np.cos(dt / 100.0) +  np.random.normal(0, 0.25, 1)[0],
        }
        return component_msg

    def send_message(self):
        """Send a message."""
        msg = self._noisy_wave_message({})

        if msg and self._msg_count <= self._msg_max:
            msg['timeStamp'] = self._time_last
            msg_body = json.dumps(msg)
            print("Sending message: %s" % msg_body)
            iot_msg = IoTHubMessage(msg_body)
            iot_msg.message_id = "message_%d" % self._msg_count
            self._client.send_event_async(iot_msg, send_confirmation_callback, None)
            self._msg_count +=1 
        self._time_last = time.time()

def start_device():
    try:
        device = SimulateDevice()
        print ( "IoT Hub device sending periodic messages, press Ctrl-C to exit" )
        while True:
            # Send the message.
            device.send_message()
    except IoTHubError as iothub_error:
        print ( "Unexpected error %s from IoTHub" % iothub_error )
        return
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print ( "IoTHubClient sample stopped" )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ( "IoT Hub Quickstart #1 - Simulated device" )
    print ( "Press Ctrl-C to exit" )
    start_device()
```

And when I check the logs, I see this

```
azureuser@EdgeVM:~$ sudo iotedge logs basic_device
IoT Hub Quickstart #1 - Simulated device
Press Ctrl-C to exit
IoT Hub device sending periodic messages, press Ctrl-C to exit
Sending message: {"noisy_sinus": -0.12927878622262406, "noisy_cosine": 0.5951663552778992, "timeStamp": 1542717185.0867708}
IoT Hub responded to message with status: OK
```

So it seems like it works right?

Then I wanted to create a module that subscribes to messages from this module. The module is rather simple, ie

```
import random
import time
import sys
import iothub_client
# pylint: disable=E0611
from iothub_client import IoTHubModuleClient, IoTHubTransportProvider
from iothub_client import IoTHubMessage, IoTHubMessageDispositionResult, IoTHubError

MESSAGE_TIMEOUT = 10000
PROTOCOL = IoTHubTransportProvider.MQTT

def noisy_sinus(message, user_context):
    print("Received a message")
    print(message)
    return IoTHubMessageDispositionResult.ACCEPTED

class AnalysisManager():
    """A class that manages different analysis for differnet signals."""

    def __init__(self, protocol=IoTHubTransportProvider.MQTT):
        self.client_protocol = protocol
        self.client = IoTHubModuleClient()
        self.client.create_from_environment(protocol)

        # set the time until a message times out
        self.client.set_option("messageTimeout", MESSAGE_TIMEOUT)

        # sets the callback when a message arrives on "input1" queue. 
        self.client.set_message_callback("input1", noisy_sinus, None)

def main(protocol):
    try:
        print ( "\nPython %s\n" % sys.version )
        print ( "IoT Hub Client for Python" )

        hub_manager = AnalysisManager(protocol)

        print ( "Starting the IoT Hub Python sample using protocol %s..." % hub_manager.client_protocol )
        print ( "The sample is now waiting for messages and will indefinitely.  Press Ctrl-C to exit. ")

        while True:
            time.sleep(1)

    except IoTHubError as iothub_error:
        print ( "Unexpected error %s from IoTHub" % iothub_error )
        return
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print ( "IoTHubModuleClient sample stopped" )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(PROTOCOL)
```

And in the routing settings, I have the following

```
"routes": {
  "basic_deviceToIoTHub": "FROM /messages/modules/basic_device/outputs/* INTO $upstream",
  "basic_analysisToIoTHub": "FROM /messages/modules/basic_analysis/outputs/* INTO $upstream",
  "sensorTobasic_analysis": "FROM /messages/modules/basic_device/outputs/* INTO BrokeredEndpoint(\"/modules/basic_analysis/inputs/input1\")"
},
```

But this one receives **no** messages at all.

```
azureuser@EdgeVM:~$ sudo iotedge logs basic_analysis

Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]

IoT Hub Client for Python
Starting the IoT Hub Python sample using protocol MQTT...
The sample is now waiting for messages and will indefinitely.  Press Ctrl-C to exit.
```

What am I missing here? I am able to receive messages from the tempSensor module if I want too.

Furthermore, in the demo, it is possible to name the message as **temperatureOutput**, however, in the Python API, there is no such option when creating a send_event_async.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some digging around I found a solution that worked.
In the basic_device module, I now use `IoTHubModuleClient` instead of `IoTHubClient`.

```
class SimulateDevice():
    def __init__(self, protocol, msg_max=100):
        self._client_protocol = protocol
        self._client = IoTHubModuleClient()
        self._client.create_from_environment(self._client_protocol)
```

Which then allows me to send a message like so

```
self._client.send_event_async("allmessages", iot_msg, send_confirmation_callback, None)
```

Then in the routing, I can use

```
"routes": {
  "basic_deviceToIoTHub": "FROM /messages/modules/basic_device/outputs/* INTO $upstream",
  "basic_analysisToIoTHub": "FROM /messages/modules/basic_analysis/outputs/* INTO $upstream",
  "sensorTobasic_analysis": "FROM /messages/modules/basic_device/outputs/allmessages INTO BrokeredEndpoint(\"/modules/basic_analysis/inputs/input1\")"
},
```

Then the analysis module is able to receive the message. I'm unsure why using "*" did not work in the previous case.

**Edit:** Fix grammar